# MySQL returns value, but variable is null

Tags: mysql

I have this stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS rankvolume $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `rankvolume`(IN theranking INT, OUT thectr INT)
BEGIN
  SELECT organic from ctrs where ranking = theranking;
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

I call it like this:

```
CALL rankvolume(2,@foo)
```

It returns .125, which is correct. YAY!

But

```
SELECT @foo
```

Returns NULL.

Booo.

I've tried renaming all variables. I double-checked that I'm not reusing any variable names.

What am I missing?

Comment: I believe you need [`SELECT ... INTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a value to `thectr`

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS rankvolume $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `rankvolume`(IN theranking INT, OUT thectr INT)
BEGIN
  SELECT organic INTO  thectr  from ctrs where ranking = theranking;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e0dff2a23512e75f55e7030d001973ab)*